# To what degree were Rabbi Akiva's five students responsible for preserving the Oral Law?

Tags: oral-torah, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef

The gemara in [Yevamos 62b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.62b) says:

> **They said** by way of example that **Rabbi Akiva had twelve thousand pairs of students** in an area of land that stretched **from Gevat to Antipatris** in Judea, **and they all died in one period** of time, **because they did not treat each other with respect**. **And the world was desolate** of Torah **until Rabbi Akiva came to our Rabbis in the South and taught** his Torah **to them**. This second group of disciples consisted of **Rabbi Meir, Rabbi Yehuda, Rabbi Yosei, Rabbi Shimon, and Rabbi Elazar ben Shamua. And these are the very ones** who **upheld** the study of **Torah at that time**. Although Rabbi Akiva’s earlier students did not survive, his later disciples were able to transmit the Torah to future generations.

I have heard people suggest that Rabbi Akiva essentially rebuilt or preserved Judaism through his five students. Is that correct? What is the proper understanding of this gemara? Were there not other Torah teachers who would have carried the torch? Is it saying that Judaism has a bottleneck in (at least parts of) the Oral Law?